# How to detect barcode has been scanned in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app where I have to generate a barcode in the app itself. I have created the barcode with following code

```
let data = codeString.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
filter?.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
self.qrCodeImage = (filter?.outputImage)!
```

someone has to scan the barcode.

Now my query is that how to detect barcode has been scanned or not? Is there any way/notification from where we can detect barcode has been scanned?

Please let me know if you need to explain my question. Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: do you want to scan QR code ?

Comment: well if it is suppose to be scaned from app then after getting meta data from scaned QR code you can through notification with required detail.

Comment: You need a delegate method for that.

Comment: @ElTomato can you please explain how

Comment: If you want to detect that your created barcode has been detected or not then it is not possible. if you have created functionality that scan's barcode then you can use `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`

Comment: Probably you want your barcode should be scan only once through your app then after scan barcode you can send that info to your server and when it been scanned again then you can verify that it has been scanned previously  nor not

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya correct